# Sort a file with unordered columns of integers

Tags: perl, bash, sorting

I have an input file with two columns of integer values. I would like to chop the input file in this way

```
 input file:
 ...
 ...
 12312 565456
 565456 12312
 ...
 ...
```

#

```
 output file:
 ...
 ...
 12312 565456
 ...
 ...
```

namely if two numbers are present in couple more then one time, writing  a unique line in the output file where the first number if the smaller of the two.

How can be done with sort or a perl script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
perl -nale ' @F=reverse @F if($F[0]>$F[1]);                 
             $x=$F[0]." ".$F[1]; if(!$h{$x}){print $x;$h{$x}=1;}'
```

[See it](http://ideone.com/v3NuA)

Answer (score 1):

You could combine `perl` and `sort`:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN { $, = " " } print sort split' infile | sort -u
```

Comment: Just a small nit: it's not clear if the user needs the input list to remain in its current order after removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vOFS="\t" '$2<$1 {print $2,$1} $1<=$2 {print}'|sort -u
```

would also work